# Why is this complex.h typedef not working?

Tags: c++, makefile, typedef, complex.h

I've been referencing published C++ code from MIT [here.](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/netmit/sFFT/code.html) I'm trying to compile the code using the provided Makefile. Note I'm using Ubuntu version 20.04 and installed g++.

From a previous question I posted here, the code seems to be tripping up over a typedef in one of the included headers:

```
#ifndef FFT_H
#define FFT_H

#include<cmath>
#include<complex.h>
#include<vector>

#define Vec(a, b) std::vector<__typeof(*(a))> ((a), (a)+(b))

// allow easy change to float or long double
//#define USE_FLOAT
#define USE_DOUBLE

#ifdef USE_FLOAT
typedef float complex complex_t;
typedef float real_t;
#define cexp cexpf
#define exp expf
#endif


#ifdef USE_DOUBLE
typedef double complex complex_t; // this is the trouble line!
typedef double real_t;
#endif

//#define DEBUG

#endif
```

The compiler complains that `double complex`is not a valid type and thus it won't define `complex_t`

Now, the original assumption was that  should be replaced with  or , however, this did not fix the issue. The compiler kept tripping up over the `typedef double complex complex_t;` line regardless of changing this header.

Now I'm also a noob when it comes to using Make. I'm trying to compile the code using the following Makefile (which was provided):

```
CC=g++
RM=rm -f
#CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Wconversion -g
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Wconversion -O2
LDFLAGS=-g
LDLIBS=-lfftw3 -lfftw3f -lm -lrt

DESTS=experiment generate_graphs kaiserbessel
SRCS:=$(filter-out $(DESTS:%=%.cc), $(wildcard *.cc))
OBJS:=$(subst .cc,.o,$(SRCS))

all: $(DESTS)
```

My current assumption is the source code is using dirty C++ and hence including complex.h (note the rest of the code is definitely C++ and not C). However, I'm also wondering if I am doing something wrong with setting up g++ and downloaded a different compiler version than what the Makefile corresponds to.

Any ideas as to how fix this typedef issue?

Comment: `<complex.h>` is a C header with C complex types that are not available in C++. You must `#include <complex>` instead

Comment: The source code suggests that "double complex" is defined somewhere. This doesn't seem to be defined in <complex> either. Do you know where it would be defined?

Comment: `double complex` expands to `double _Complex` in C. There's no `_Complex` type in C++ as I said. Either compile as C or use `std::complex`. C and C++ tackle complex types very differently

Comment: Fair enough, can you comment on the make file? I'm confused as to why why "CC=g++". Shouldn't it be "CXX=g++"?

Comment: @Izzo That SFFT codebase is horribly broken. You have to change the complex_t type to std::complex<double> then follow the errors down. There are an absolute ton of them. Unfortunately, all SFFT codes I could find also have this error and so you can't escape it without rewriting everything. It is incredibly tedious and what you get is essentially your own custom library. I have no idea how the authors got the OG code to work.